# HTML5 animation - play when scrolled to

Tags: html, animation, css

I want to have a few HTML5 animations on one page but don't want them all to play at once/when the page loads. Instead I'd like for each animation to auto-play when a user scrolls to the section where each animation is. What is the appropriate tag, code, etc. to make that happen?

A couple of examples elsewhere:
nest.com/living-with-nest/
- When you scroll down to day 2 the blue and orange arrows animate in

apple.com/ipad/features/
- When you scroll down to the camera section, the lens video/vr plays
- Same with the Smart Cover, Airplay and other sections

Thanks!

Comment: I have done research. Probably over 2 hours at this point.

Comment: your question is not specific at all. You're asking a very broad question thats why it sounds like you haven't made any effort. If I google HTML5 animation, it'll come up with loads of Canvas tutorials and jQuery/javascript animation examples. If I copy one of those and build on it and get stuck, then ask a question 'Why isn't this working' or something else but very specific and show the code i've written then people would be more likely to answer and help me.

Comment: I'm a Flash guy new to HTML5 so the question doesn't seem that broad to me, especially with the examples I cited. I'll respond further to this after I figure out what I'm doing (hopefully with help from folks.)

Comment: Now that you mentioned Flash it becomes apparent what you probably are looking for is the Canvas object. So here's something to start you off: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial. Javascript is very similar to Actionscript so you shouldn't be having much trouble. The thing which javascript lacked from actionscript was the canvas & svg drawing abilities which you get in HTML5

Answer (score 2):

Different parts in your question :

- Have html5 animations : use the `video` element
- not start animations immediately : simply don't specify `autoplay`
- start the video :

  ```
  document.getElementById('myVideo').play();
  ```
- check if an element is visible : using jquery you can simply use offset().top, window.innerHeight and scrollTop :

  ```
  var visible = 
      $(window).scrollTop()+window.innerHeight>$e.offset().top
      &&$(window).scrollTop()<$e.offset().top+$e.height(); // $e is the video element
  ```
- detect scrolling : use the jquery `scroll` function

I made a fiddle to illustrate how you can detect when the scrolling reveals or hides an element : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/zj5Sz/

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This answer is specific to Animate CC(Flash) generated HTML5 projects as you mentioned in the comment*

There is now a quick and easy way of controlling such settings using Animate CC & Muse 2017.

1. Export your Animation as an OAM file or upload the animation to CC Libraries,.
2. Open your website in Muse.
3. Import the OAM file or use the Animation from CC libraries in Muse. Place it at the appropriate position.
4. Open Scroll Effects Panel in Muse -> goto Animation tab -> select Animation checkbox and Autoplay selected.

   [image]
5. Preview the webpage in browser and it should play only when you scroll down and canvas comes in view.